Create spectra matrix plot in ggplot
I am trying to create a 'spectra matrix' plot of type:
I have a series of spectra, and want to plot each spectra on a plot as the first image shows, with the x axis denoting the position in the spectra, the y axis denoting the time the spectra was taken and the colour denoting the intensity value of that position for each spectra. I currently have plots which have x as position, y as the intensity and then I use a gradient to show the time:
I have tried using geom_raster(aes(fill =intensity)) however my laptop got very hot and after 10 minutes didn't produce an image (while saying I was running at 100 % memory usage). I checked my memory.limit() and it already quite high (16056). Is there a better way to do this?
Something which maybe makes things harder is that my x values are logarithmically spaced.
